# Can I name a column a variable in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Google sheets allows you to set a particular cell as variable so I can set A1=JimsHeight

But is there a way to name an entire column and use it as variable?

Then I might set A = height so that I can use height1, height2 to represent A1, A2 etc. in a formula?

UseCase is in order to be able to drag down a formula.

Comment: Yes https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175

Answer (score 1):

No, `I might set A = height so that I can use height1, height2 to represent A1, A2 etc. in a formula?` is not possible.

What you can do is giving `height` to the header (i.e. A1) of the column, then use for instance

```
=offset(height,2,)
```

for A3

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

- Add a named range for your column (see [Name a range of cells](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175)):

[image]

- Call [INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en) on the named range to get your desired cell:

```
=INDEX(height,2)
```

[image]